# Explanation on the dependent variable in a logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic

In logistic regression, I often see this picture:

[image]

And according to literature, the logistic regression is performed as
$$\ln \left({\frac {p(x)}{1-p(x)}}\right)=\beta _{0}+\beta _{1}x,$$

I would like to ask on the calculation of $p(x)$. If $p(x)$ equals 1 (0) as in this picture, the odds ratio $\ln \left({\frac {p(x)}{1-p(x)}}\right)$ would be undefined.

From my understanding, the correct translation would be $p(x)=\hat{p}$ when $Y=1$ and $p(x)=1-\hat{p}$ when $Y=0$ (where $\hat{p}$ representing the relative proportion of 1s in the sample).

Is this correct?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "$Y=1$" and what the "relative proportion of 1s" might be?  After all, in this model you are given $x$ *and wish to estimate $\Pr(Y)$*, so how can "$Y=1$" make any sense?

Comment: The value of x affects p. The indicator variable doesn't seem to reflect this.

Comment: I think Bill Huber and I are asking the same question.  In the graph,it looks like the dots represent observed values for Y.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the plot, but I would interpret it as saying... If we were to classify as "yes" (1) when the probability is 0.5 or higher, we would draw a vertical line that would misclassify the points on the right side of the bottom row of blue points (false positives), and the blue points on the left on the top row (false negatives).

Comment: In fact what you model is the probability that $Y=1$ for a given value of $x$, i.e. $P(Y=1|_{x})$ and this depends on $x$, it is $P(Y=1|_{x})=\frac{1}{1+e^{-\beta_0-\beta_1x}}$. So for each value of $x$ you get a Bernoulli random variable with success probability $\frac{1}{1+e^{-\beta_0-\beta_1x}}$. The coefficients $\beta_i$ are estimated by maximum likelihood from a sample with values for $x_i$ and the corresponding outcome $Y_i \in \{0,1\}$, $i=1 ..N$, where $N$ is the sample size.

Comment: @fcop On Wikipedia, the article states that one does not use the realized values of $Y$, but the "Odds ratio": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Logistic_function.2C_odds.2C_odds_ratio.2C_and_logit

Comment: @fcop According to your comment, a logistic regression is a "plain" linear regression with $Y=a+bX$ with $Y\in\{0,1\}$ and the only difference being  that the forecasted probability is calculated as $\frac{1}{1+e^{-a+bX}}$?

Comment: If you want to know all about it then Google : Hosmer lemeshow applied logistic regression pdf and you will have a good book on it

Comment: @fcop I dont have time to read this book, I am only looking to understand the value of $Y$ for the regression $Y=a+bX$.

Comment: There is no such linear regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logistic regression is working with a latent variable: the *probability* that a realization would take on $y_i = 1$.  It does not predict the actual observed / realized $y_i$ values.  So the sets of $(x_i,\ y_i)$ values that you have in your dataset are only indirectly informative about the function that logistic regression is trying to find.  What would be ideal would be to have a dataset composed of sets of $(x_i,\ p_i(Y=1))$ instead.  Since you don't have that, logistic regression models are fit using an iterative search algorithm.  Candidate betas are plugged into the formula
$$
\hat p_i(Y=1) = \frac{\exp(\hat\beta_0 + \hat\beta_1x_i)}{1+\exp(\hat\beta_0 + \hat\beta_1x_i)}
$$
to compute the set of estimated $\hat p_i(Y=1)$s.  Using those, you can compute the log likelihood and/or deviance associated with the model based on those candidate betas.  The fitting algorithm searches for the best fitting (i.e., maximum log likelihood or minimum deviance) model by working through a series of progressively better fitting candidate betas.  There are a number of different search algorithms that can be used, but none use $y_i$ as $p_i(x_i)$.

Comment: So the dataset would be composed of $(x_i,p_i(Y=1))$ and I presume $p_i(Y=1)$ would be estimated as $\sum y_i/n$ (i.e. the relative sample frequency). So then $p_i(Y=1)$ is a constant (given that the only available information is a sample of $y_i\in\{0,1\}$). (??)

Comment: No, what would be ideal would be to have $p_i(Y=1)$; those wouldn't be estimated, they would be the true probabilities. Whether the probabilities are constant depends on whether x is related to y or not. In the real world, there is no linear regression method to do this. The (log) likelihood (or the deviance) is maximized (or minimized) via an iterative search algorithm.